# Bind DataGrid Column to Element of Array in Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I got an `Assignments` list that is bound to my `DataGrid`, this results in rows for every `Assignment` that I got.

Now I want to bind every `Motors` element to its own column. How would I realize this with DataBinding?

```
public class Motor {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Assignment {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Motor> Motors { get; set; }
}

public class AssignmentViewModel {
  public ObservableCollection<Assignment> Assignments{ get; set; }
}

<Window xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyMotors.ViewModel">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:AssignmentViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Assignments}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Motor0"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Motor1"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Motor2"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Motor3"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

The grid should look something like that in the end (columns don't need to be dynamic generated):

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Name          | Motor0    | Motor1    | Motor2    | Motor3    |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Assignment0   | Motor00   | Motor10   | Motor20   | Motor30   |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Assignment1   | Motor01   | Motor11   | Motor21   | Motor31   |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Assignment2   | Motor02   | Motor12   | Motor22   | Motor32   |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Currently I have for every column a own CellTemplate that binds directly to the value like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=Motors[0]}"
```

But thats tedious if I ever want to add new columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DataGridTextColumns` that binds to different indexes of the `Motors` collection:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Assignments}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Motor0" Binding="{Binding Motors[0].Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Motor1" Binding="{Binding Motors[1].Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Motor2" Binding="{Binding Motors[2].Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Motor3" Binding="{Binding Motors[3].Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Problem with `DataGridTextColumn` that you can't create your own `DataTemplate` for them (or at least i don't know how to do that).

Comment: Why do you want to create your own DataTemplate in this case?

Comment: I need to display a bit more than just the Name of my motor. And I have to implement Drag&Drop to move the motors to a different assigment. So if i get the `SelectedItem` i need my `Motor`-object because the Name could be equal for different motors

Comment: So your question is basically how to reuse the same template for several motors?

Comment: This would sum it up. Currently i have one template for every motor. I the question there are only  4 but i could have up to 32, so i would have 32 times the same code. it's a pain if I ever need to change something on the cell template

Comment: Your best shot would then be to create the template, or at least set the DataContext of it, programmatically.

Comment: Will have a look into that tomorrow. Already left work for today :)

Comment: OK setting the DataContext of the cells programmatically doesn't work. There is no simple way to get the cells by row and column index. Everytging involves getting the child elements of the row with `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` or `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount` wich resulted in `null` or no childs in my case